# debug a remote wildfly instance from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, wildfly

I've set up a VM with a wildfly instance.

I'd like to be able to debug my web application from eclipse.

I've took a look on the web, however, I've not been able to figure out how to do it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Install JBoss Tools into Eclipse IDE, and then you can use the features described in http://tools.jboss.org/blog/2015-03-17-debugging-an-externally-launched-wildfly.html

Comment: I've already installed it on my eclipse instance. However I realized I'm only be able to connect with a Wildfly 8.x

Comment: Are you using latest version of Eclipse IDE and JBoss Tools?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse 4.4.2 (`Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) - Build id: 20150219-0600`) and JBoss Tools 4.2.3.Final

Comment: Ok, those are probably too recent wildfly releases. Please try out latest Eclipse and latest JBoss Tools.

Comment: I've just updated everything and I'm using Eclipse Neon Release (4.6.0) and JBoss Tools 4.4.1.Final. So now I'm able to create a Wildfly-10 server. Nevertheless, I'm not quite to figure out how to connect to a remote one... As far I've been able to get, the lick you has provided me is trying to connect the debugger to a local process... So, I'm running my Wildfly-10 instance on a virtual machine and I don't see how to connect to a remote wildfly instance. Any ideas?

Comment: I believe explanation in http://tools.jboss.org/blog/2015-03-17-debugging-an-externally-launched-wildfly.html is still valid.